# problems deploying a .jsp in Eclipse with Maven?

Tags: java, eclipse, apache, maven

I'm working on a Java Web project with Eclipse and Maven, and an Apache server for the first time.

I have changed code in a .jsp file, how can I compile it? Have i need to re-deploy the module? 
When I redeploy I saw the changes from the previous version to the current one, not the one I just saved, so I have redeploy two times.
I tried to do a refresh and publish in eclispe, clean, clean install in maven, restart the Apache server, etc. and I do not see the changes. what I am doing wrong?

help please :)

Comment: Try this : Right click Your main project - > run As -> Run on server.

Comment: Are you running your server locally or on an external device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it changing directly de jsp from de deployed folder, with a normal txt editor. this do what i wanted. Thank you a lot :)